# UWP: why does FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout fail for Button

Tags: button, uwp, flyout

I have a `Button` declared in XAML with a `Button.Flyout` nested element. I'm catching the button click and then wish to show the flyout. But I get an error:

```
ShowAttached was called on an element without an attached FlyoutBase.
```

Here's the XAML:

```
      <Button ... Click="onMoreClicked">
        <Image Source="..." />
        <Button.Flyout > 
         ...
        </Button.Flyout>
      </Button>
```

And, here's my handler:

```
public void onMoreClicked (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Log.L("LP OnMoreClicked");
  Button element = sender as Button;
  FlyoutBase flyout = element.Flyout as FlyoutBase;
  FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
}
```

When stepping in the debugger, element and flyout are defined, i.e. not null. Yet, `ShowAttachedFlyout` fails.

EDIT

For clarity, using the answer from @AryaDing-MSFT, here is my working solution:

```
<Button ... Click="onMoreClicked">
  <Image Source="..." />
  <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout> 
   ...
  </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Button>
```

Handler:

```
public void onMoreClicked (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button button = sender as Button;
  ... do stuff ...
  FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(button);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by not using **FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout** to attach property, FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout and FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout need to be used together.

Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/flyouts#how-to-create-a-flyout), if the control doesn't have a flyout property, you can use the [FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.AttachedFlyoutProperty?view=winrt-19041) attached property instead. When you do this, you also need to call the [FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBase?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_FlyoutBase_ShowAttachedFlyout_Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_) method to show the flyout.

So you can refer to the code like following.

XAML:

```
<Button Click="onMoreClicked">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
          <Flyout>
             <TextBlock Text="This is a flyout!"/>
          </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>             
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void onMoreClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
    }
```

Because the button has a flyout attribute, you can also write directly like following.

```
<Button>
     <Button.Flyout >
         <Flyout>
            <TextBlock Text="This is a flyout!"/>
          </Flyout>
      </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Comment: Interesting. Using `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` works. The second solution you present (which is identical to my OP) does not work. Why is this difference significant ?

Comment: How do you set AttachedFlyout in the code behind?